# Showing that span$\{x,Ix\}$ is an invarient subspace of $V:=\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V := R^n$ be a vector space and let $I \in O(n)$ be an operator satisfying $I^2 = -Id$. I want to show that the $span\{x,Ix\}$ is an invarient subspace of $I$.

Let $W = span\{x,Ix\}$. I need to show that $IW \subseteq W$. That is, if we transform $W$ by $I$, then we are still within $W$. But, my linear algebra is bad and i'm struggling to figure how to do this. Can anyone show me how to do this or offer advice?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Can you think of a way to write a vector in $W$ in general form?

Comment: @HansEngler By definition, a vector in $W$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $Ix$. So $c_1 x + c_2 Ix$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any vector, v, in span(x, Ix) can be written v= ax+ bIx.  Then Iv= I(ax+ bIx)= aIx+ bI^2x= -bx+ aIx which is again in span(x, Ix).

Comment: Why Is $x$ and $Ix$ orthogonal? I am trying to show that their dot product is $0$, but after writing $x^{T}Ix$, I am not sure how to write this as a sum.

Answer (score 0):

We can write any $y \in W$ in the form $y = ax + bIx$. From there, we see that 
$$
Iy = I(ax + bIx) = aIx + bI^2x = (-b)x + (a)Ix
$$
so, we can conclude that the vector $Iy$ is in $W$.

Answer (score 0):

After applying the transformation we have that $IW=span\{Ix,-x\}$. Therefore any element $v$ in $IW$ can be written as $v=b(Ix)+c(-x)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ which we can rewrite as $v=a(x)+b(Ix)$ by simply letting $a=-c$. Thus we have that $v\in IW$ implies $v \in W$